# I'd like to scale something up to mark seams, how would I scale it the equivalent down?

Tags: modeling

I will be scaling it by 50 - what would be the equivalent scaling it down?

Comment: What kind of seams do you want to mark, UV seams?

Comment: Yes, UV seams ^ I'd like to know how to scale it down on the same scale I scale it up.

Answer (score 1):

You would scale it by `1/50` which equals `0.02`

Answer (score 0):

When you scale something, it keeps track of the scale in the object properties menu.

This 'scale information' gets reset to 1 when you 'apply scale' with the Ctrl + A menu.

[image]

To "undo" your scale operation, simply change the scale back to 1/1/1 and you'll be good to go.